# Need to turn off sticky header((vardhmangroup.org/projects)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my website (www.vardhmangroup.org/projects). I need to turn off the sticky header or make email id and phone number fix (it should not hide after scrolling)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your header fixed with email id and phone number you need to remove or comment this css code in your files line 506

```
/*.header-style-one.fixed-header .info-box {
    opacity: 0; 
    visibility: hidden; 
    margin-top: -200px; 
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}*/
```

and also remove previously added css

```
.header-style-one {
      position: relative !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To turn off sticky add this class in your css.

```
.header-style-one {
      position: relative !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks  but it's not working. it makes header hide on scroll. actually it turns off the sticky header. but i need to show sticky header along with the email id and phone number.